# What steps are needed to safely create a unix setuid binary that can mount removable drives without privilege escalation

Tags: unix, mount, privileges, setuid

The steps I can think of for a setuid binary that is willing to mount drives on arbitrary paths specified by normal users:

- the binary must check whether `/sys/block/DEV/removable`=1
- the binary must check whether the directory to be mounted at is owned by the invoking user
- the binary must always mount with `-o nosuid,uid=UID,gid=GID` for the invoking user

Are there any more I overlooked?

Traditionally noexec is added to the mount options as well but I'm not sure whether that's strictly necessary to avoid privilege escalation.

Comment: Mount options like uid and gid do not even apply on Linux filesystems. (But well, I won't argue if you say removale drive shell be used with a Windows filesystem...). Also, the idea of "removable" is really vague. In reality, USB HDDs/SSDs do not advertise SCSI RMB=1. (Neither should they, IMO, because of how Windows take the bit into consideration.) "external" might be a more concrete idea...

Comment: `the binary must check whether the directory to be mounted at is owned by the invoking user` I'm not so sure if that matters at all. Permission does not work on the basis of path.

Comment: Besides, what you are considering does not seem to be related to "privilege escalation" to me. Shouldn't your concern be things like "how to prevent the binary from being used for things other than mounting"?

Comment: Have to ask: There are several existing programs that are meant for exactly this. Have you looked into the way they've been written and the options they use?

Comment: @TomYan if you can mount on a directory you don't own, you can simply overwrite /etc and thus /etc/password and /etc/shadow with an arbitrary file and easily gain root. That would be a form of privilege escalation. The reason mounting is a root operation is because there are many, many ways arbitrarily mounting can be used to achieve root. Mount does not require that the directory mounted on be empty.

Comment: @u1686_grawity they all rely on polkit and dbus being installed which isn't really an option for my use case. I'm also simply interested in the theory security theory behind mounting.

Comment: @Zorf: they don't; pmount, for example.